# How to input timeslots into database efficiently

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am student that is creating a booking system for my project.

```
      9:00 AM    10:00 AM  11:00 AM ...  21:00PM
5 / 1 / 2017 ||   A          A         A
6 / 1 / 2017 ||   A          A         B
7 / 1 / 2017 ||   A          B         B
.
.
.
.
1 / 4 / 2017 ||   A          A         A

Where A = Available, B = Booked.
```

I wanted to manually input the timeslots but i find that it is too tedious.
Is there any easier method to input these large amount of timeslots data in to my database.

I am using phpmyadmin database.

---

Comment: In what form is the data stored currently?

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: Is there a pattern?  Such as the same 12 hours for every day in the future?  Do you also have A/B to fill in?

Comment: Do _not_ use a column per hour; have a row per hour per day.

Answer (score 0):

Have your application code (you do have code in front of MySQL, don't you?  Phpmyadmin does not count.) create a new row on demand.  This will also solve what to do after April 1st (or is that Jan 4th?)

Any missing rows are "empty" slots.